# How can I choose the language and database for my C# application?

Tags: c#, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm working on a collaborative real-time drawing tool. My client is already written in C# and I need a server. I've done a lot of search on google, but I don't know how to choose a database and a language for the server side. I'm a beginner and I would like to have your help. In my database I need to store users information and their pictures, also users can chat together, so I'll be using sockets. Is it possible to build my server with nodeJs and a mongoDB database or C# and SQL. Also, what makes this difficult for me to choose is how can I store pictures (that users are working on) in my database and always sync with changes. Is that possible with Json (image represented by an array of bytes?) or there is another way for storing pictures and update them whenever a change is made by a user?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of opinions will go into into my answer, but here goes...

Some assumptions -

1. Since your asking, your team size is approximately 1.
2. Since the team size is ~1, the customer base is smallish.
3. Since chat is not the primary function of the product, price, simplicity and time are important.
4. You know your way around the existing app, thus you are already familiar with C#, and also comfortable with nodeJS, SQL and mongoDB.

So ask yourself -

1. Firstly, what are you best at? What are you most familiar with? Do you have time constraints that can be best served with a more familiar stack?
2. What about storing your images in AWS S3 or similar cloud storage? Persisting binary data into an SQL database is not ideal, and it quickly causes issues with managing the size of your database backups.
3. What are the requirements for uptime/availability and scale?
4. Is there an off-the-shelf alternative chat program that you can plug in so that you have NO back-end? (i.e. freshdesk)
5. You database decision comes down to requirements. Lots of possibly irrelevant questions here i.e.

   1. Does the user need to see their old chat?
   2. How many users in a chat room?
   3. How long do chat messages have to stick around for?
   4. If no one is available on the other end, how will this work? How do you match users?
   5. What reporting or administrative requirements are there?
   6. Are there lots of object types with complex relationships between them that are best stored in an SQL DB?

Some recommendations -

- Keep your database small - don't persist chat logs or purge them as soon as you can; Keep files over a few KB out of the db
- If you choose .NET, consider WCF or signalR for communications
- If you don't have to store chat logs, consider a memory database like redis with pub-sub capability
- If you have to support and maintain the server, consider instead a Linux OS and compatible stack so your not woken up in the middle of the night when a Windows Update fails and the machine wont boot.
- Consider virtualization. i.e. open up a free-ish AWS account and sniff around what technologies you could cobble together to do much of the work for you - a few lambda functions and you may not even need a server!

Personal favorites -

- Linux
- Redis for pub-sub and chat
- object store (mongo/dynamo whatever) for user profile
- S3 or comparable for images

Answer (score 1):

The stack you choose is up to you but if you coded client in C# then it would be simplest to stay with that stack.

For me right now to do this task I would create a web api in ASP.NET Core 2.0.  This will handle all the user info and image uploading as well as authentication.

I would use Entityframework Core which is an ORM that can map to any database you want (although support may vary).  The new SQL Server Express runs on windows and linux so I would probably choose that.  For the chat you can use SignalR.

Really it doesn't matter so much what you use as long as it can accomplish the job but if you are just starting out it make sense to pick a reasonably new stack (although not bleeding edge or you may have difficulty finding adequate documentation).

Comment: Thanks for this info. I dont even know that SIgnalR because Im always using SqlDependency for Real-Time update.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good place to start is make sure you understand the following:

- Difference between a 'database', 'database management system(DBMS)' and 'SQL'
- SQL vs NoSQL DBMS. How is data stored and accessed for each?

mangoDB is a NOoQL DBMS. MySQL is a SQL DBMS.

JSON is a file format for representing data. Think of XML. It has nothing to do with arrays of bytes.

When you have clients collaborating on a picture, your server application will probably want to keep the picture in memory to allow for fast editing. You will want to save it to the database every once in a while. You can do that in many ways. You could also decide you want to store the files as bitmaps on the servers hard disk.

Most applications have a single instance of the server handling multiple clients so you want your server application to be written in a faster language. That being said with today technology and the scope of your application, pretty much any language will do.